# Jquery addClass works for width and height but not for background and color

Tags: jquery, each, addclass

I have this jquery issue that makes me scratch my head. I want to addClass to each list item. While list items do increase in width and height, background and color do not change. Why? Thank you.

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".userarea_nav li").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.selected{
    background: blue;
    color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Conflicting CSS rules? Can you demonstrate via a fiddle? P.S. `$(".userarea_nav li").addClass("selected")` would suffice. No need to iterate with the `.each`

Comment: Does it work if you add the class to the `li` element in the html?  That would at least rule out any conflicts.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/MLsDd/ - I'm guessing it's to do with Anton's answer and your `background` property is being ignored.

Comment: yes thats it it was conflicting css. I had list background already determined and it did not override this by addClass. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try !important if you already have css background for li

```
.selected{
    background: blue !important;
    color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[**DEMO without important**](http://jsfiddle.net/fEUGW/2/)

[**DEMO with important**](http://jsfiddle.net/fEUGW/3/)

Comment: I think this is the issue they're experiencing. On a side note, if they're only using the `selected` class for these elements then they might be able to use `.userarea_nav li.selected` as a more specific selector instead of `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

CSS

```
.selected{
    background-color: Green!important;
    color: Yellow!important;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("userarea_nav li").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pzrN2/)

Answer (score 1):

Using Firefox, you can use the Firebug extension (http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect the DOM and the css.
Using Chrome and IExplorer 8+ you can use built-in inspection tools.

You will be able to find out which CSS rules is actually applied to the "selected" list item.

Check if there is a CSS rule with higher priority for the list item.

The priority of a rule can be determined by:

- the position of the rule (between two equivalent priority rule, the last one is applied)
- the !important modifier: it raise up the priority
- the selector: more specific is the selector, higher is the priority